# How can I limit my query output to the sum of the schema contents (and eliminate the sum on TABLE_NAME)?

Tags: oracle, sum, calculated-columns

A question, potentially stupid and/or potentially very easy for some of you .....

My query:

```
BREAK ON OWNER skip 1
col OWNER format a8
col GRANTEE format a10
col TABLE_NAME format a26
col PRIVILEGE format a12
set pages 1000 lines 180
select OWNER, GRANTEE, TABLE_NAME, PRIVILEGE, count(*) NUM_VIEWS
from dba_tab_privs 
where GRANTEE like '%AAAAA%' 
and (OWNER like 'BBBBB%' or OWNER='CCCCC')
group by OWNER, GRANTEE, TABLE_NAME, PRIVILEGE
order by OWNER, GRANTEE, TABLE_NAME;
```

My output:

```
OWNER    GRANTEE   TABLE_NAME                 PRIVILEGE     NUM_VIEWS
-------- --------- -------------------------- ------------ ----------
CCCCC    AAAAA     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx SELECT                1
         AAAAA     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx SELECT                1
         AAAAA     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx SELECT                1
         AAAAA     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx SELECT                1
         AAAAA     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx SELECT                1
         AAAAA     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx SELECT                1
         AAAAA     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx SELECT                1
         AAAAA     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx SELECT                1
         AAAAA     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx SELECT                1
         AAAAA     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx SELECT                1
         AAAAA     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx SELECT                1
********                                                   ----------
sum                                                                11

BBBBB    DDDDDDD    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx SELECT               1
         DDDDDDD    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx SELECT               1
         DDDDDDD    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx SELECT               1
         DDDDDDD    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx SELECT               1
         DDDDDDD    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx SELECT               1
         DDDDDDD    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx SELECT               1
         DDDDDDD    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx SELECT               1
         DDDDDDD    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx SELECT               1
         DDDDDDD    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx SELECT               1
         DDDDDDD    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx SELECT               1
         DDDDDDD    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx SELECT               1
         DDDDDDD    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx SELECT               1
         DDDDDDD    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx SELECT               1
********                                                   ----------
sum                                                                13
```

My *desired* output:

```
OWNER    GRANTEE   TABLE_NAME                 PRIVILEGE     NUM_VIEWS
-------- --------- -------------------------- ------------ ----------
CCCCC    AAAAA     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx SELECT                
         AAAAA     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx SELECT                
         AAAAA     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx SELECT                
         AAAAA     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx SELECT                
         AAAAA     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx SELECT                
         AAAAA     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx SELECT                
         AAAAA     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx SELECT                
         AAAAA     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx SELECT                
         AAAAA     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx SELECT                
         AAAAA     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx SELECT                
         AAAAA     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx SELECT                
********                                                   ----------
sum                                                                11

BBBBB    DDDDDDD    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx SELECT                
         DDDDDDD    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx SELECT                
         DDDDDDD    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx SELECT                
         DDDDDDD    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx SELECT                
         DDDDDDD    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx SELECT                
         DDDDDDD    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx SELECT                
         DDDDDDD    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx SELECT                
         DDDDDDD    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx SELECT                
         DDDDDDD    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx SELECT                
         DDDDDDD    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx SELECT                
         DDDDDDD    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx SELECT                
         DDDDDDD    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx SELECT                
         DDDDDDD    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx SELECT                
********                                                   ----------
sum                                                                13
```

What's the best way to achieve that please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks JNevill, no pb. My desired output doesn't contain the "SELECT                1" - which is 1 for all rows.

Comment: Look into `GROUP BY ROLLUP`.

Comment: OH! Thank you! I completely overlooked it.